# PHP check if options are in json file

Tags: php, json

How can i get PHP to check if my select options are in the JSON file, if so it should echo out. Below is my items.txt

```
<select id="name">
<option value="9171">Blackout</option>
<option value="5063">Blue Electric Guitar</option>
<option value="6167">Blue Skater Shoes</option>
<option value="5208">Boom Mic</option>
<option value="4917">Brady&#8217;s Beach Outfit</option>
<option value="4938">Brady&#8217;s Biker Outfit</option>
<option value="6193">Brady&#8217;s Shoes</option>
<option value="6192">Brady&#8217;s Sneakers</option>
<option value="5342">Brady&#8217;s Surfboard</option>
<option value="6157">Break a Leg Cast</option>
<option value="5228">Brown Leather Watch</option>
<option value="2126">Bubble Gum</option>
<option value="1668">Butchy&#8217;s Bike Helmet</option>
<option value="6186">Butchy&#8217;s Boots</option>
<option value="5343">Butchy&#8217;s Gloves</option>
<option value="4915">Butchy&#8217;s Outfit</option>
<option value="9217">Cadence&#8217;s Aug 2013 Giveaway</option>
<option value="7160">Calculator Pin</option>
<option value="9025">Castle Hallway Background</option>
<option value="9066">Cave Entrance Background</option>
<option value="9092">Cave Gate</option>
<option value="9063">A Day At The Beach Background</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to search through "media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json" and then echo out the options above arranged by ID by PHP?

Comment: Is it your homework? Show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your text file line by line using `fgets()` or similar, store the the required values in an array.

And then, you can use `file_get_contents()` or `cURL` to get the contents of the remote JSON file and use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) with `TRUE` as second parameter to convert it into an associative array. :

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json');
$json = json_decode($str, TRUE);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    # code for checking...
}
```

Inside the foreach loop, you can check if your select options matches the values in your decoded JSON (using regular expressions, `strpos()` , or similar).